# What's the relationship between Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality and Extended Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I'm learning multivariate analysis.  Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality plays an important role in several multivariate techniques.

> 1. Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality:Let b and d be any two p $\times$ 1
>      vectors. Then $$(b'd)^2\leq(b'b)(d'd)$$
> 2. Extended  Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality:Let b and d be any two p $\times$
>      1 vectors and B be a p $\times$ p positive definite matrix. Then
>      $$(b'd)^2\leq(b'Bb)(d'B^{-1}d)$$

It is not that difficult to prove. I'm **NOT** asking how to prove it.

*My question:*

Consider there is a p $\times$ p identity matrix in the right hand of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, that is, (b'Ib)(d'Id). Why can we  turn I into a positive definite matrix so that the Inequality still remains? How to understand this fact intuitively?

Comment: Is the LHS of 2. correct? Shouldn't there be a B there also?

Comment: @Berci No. It's just 1. applied to $B^{1/2}b$ and $B^{-1/2}d$.

Comment: @Berci I copied 1 and 2 from P78-P79 of Applied Multivariate Statistical Analysis written by Richard A. Johnson. I'm sure there is no typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say, it's about the possible *scalar products* one can impose on a given vector space.

If $B$ is a positive definite (symmetric) matrix, then $(u,v)\mapsto u'Bv$ just defines a scalar product. Cauchy-Schwarz inequality holds for any scalar product.

Comment: In fact any positive definite $B$ gives a scalar product, the symmetric $B$ is just the one that is canonically associated to it (in a given basis).

Comment: Well, the mapping above is symmetric only if $B=B'$. But, we can take $\displaystyle\frac{B+B'}2$ for any given positive definite $B$.